# Doing operations on a file literally called %A% in command prompt

Tags: cmd

In command prompt, anything between %'s is interpreted as a variable.

Say I have a folder called %A% that I want to delete. If I type rmdir %A%, it will look for a variable called A and delete the value of that variable.

Is there a way to have it literally delete %A%?

Comment: Did you try using `rmdir "%A%"`?

Comment: @Tico works only, if `%A%` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `rmdir ^%A^%`? The caret is the escape character for CMD.

Comment: Ah, escape characters. I should have thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly in windows 10 I can't replicate this behavior.

Remove Folder (CMD PROMPT)

```
rmdir %A%
```

Delete File (CMD PROMPT)

```
DEL %B%
```

My assumption is you're trying to do this from a Batch File.
The correct method to do this is

```
DEL %%B%%
```

Batch escapes using double special characters (for characters that don't allow ^ as an escape character).

Comment: Turns out it's a mixture of your answer and wilx's.

Just doing rmdir %%D%% gets turned into rmdir %D% in the command prompt, so that still looks for the variable.

The solution from bash is rmdir ^%%D^%%